# Visual studio doesn't show folders when starting new project

Tags: visual-studio

When I open an empty project in Visual Studio 2013, I don't see any subfolders such as 'source files', 'resource files' etc. How can I fix this?

Comment: @BartoszKP That solved it. So simple yet so frustrating when you can't figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: I've added this as an answer - you can mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Choose `View` -> `Solution explorer` to show the panel with projects and source files.